# Adding new dependency in bower on sage wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

I am trying to add new bower components in sage wp theme, only problem is that i can only add in manyaly in sass?

This is my **bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "sage",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/sage/",
  "authors": [
    "Ben Word <ben@benword.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "pushy": "1.0.0",
    "fullpage.js": "2.9.2"
  }
}
```

But in **main.scss** nothing is added?

```
// Automatically injected Bower dependencies via wiredep (never manually edit this block)
// bower:scss
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
// endbower
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run the bower install command you must add the --save flag to the end of it for it to update everything.